# How to create column group in WiredTiger engine in mongodb 2.8?

Tags: mongodb, columnstore

MongoDB 2.8 [supports WiredTiger](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.8/) strorage engine, and WiredTiger supports [column grouping](http://source.wiredtiger.com/1.6.5/schema.html#schema_column_groups).

How we can create a collection in mongodb 2.8 with grouped columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although WiredTiger itself does support a column stores, this is not supported with MongoDB.  WiredTiger as implemented in MongoDB only supports [LSM trees](http://source.wiredtiger.com/2.4.1/lsm.html) and the [default row-store](http://source.wiredtiger.com/2.4.1/file_formats.html).